# "CS1513 } expected" when I already have a }

Tags: c#

I've just been trying to write this small section of code and this CS1513 error keeps showing.

I've looked for any stray semi-colons, braces, and I cant' find any.  The code worked fine before I tried adding the try-catch.
I'm new to C#, so if its something obvious, please tell me, because I can't see anything.

```cs
private static void MakePlayerMove(ref char[,] Board, ref ShipType[] Ships, ref int count)
    {
        int Row = 0, Column = 0, hitCount = 0;
        bool missile = true;
        GetRowColumn(ref Row, ref Column, ref missile);
        if (Board[Row, Column] == 'm' || Board[Row, Column] == 'h')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you have already shot at the square (" + Column + "," + Row + "). Please try again.");
        }
        else if (missile == false)
        {
            if (Board[Row, Column] == '-')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, (" + Column + "," + Row + ") is a miss.");
                Board[Row, Column] = 'm';
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hit at (" + Column + "," + Row + ").");
                Board[Row, Column] = 'h';
            }
        }
        try
        { //This one is causing the problem
            else if (missile == true)
            {
                Row -= 1;
                Column -= 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        if (Board[Row, Column] != '-')
                        {
                            hitCount += 1;
                        }
                        Column += 1;
                    }
                    Row += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value that is not on the edge of the board.");
            count += 1;
            throw;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"You have {29 - count} turns left.");
    }
```

Comment: well you can use else if as first statement inside a try(because you are missing an if), you need to restructure your code

Comment: You can't put the `else if` outside the block it pertains to. The `try` starts a new block.

Comment: Put the try catch block inside the `else if (missile ==true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
try
{ //This one is causing the problem
   else if (missile == true)
   {
   }
}
catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException)
{
}
```

to

```
else if (missile == true)
{
   try
   { 
   }
   catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException)
   {
   }
}
```

---

## IndexOutOfRangeException

You shouldn't really have to deal with `IndexOutOfRangeException` - making the code not throw it a significantly better option.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious to face errors at first and in fact it's important ,they indicate that you are trying. Coming to the question you asked.

Is this a valid Statement??

```
private static void MakePlayerMove(ref char[,] Board, ref ShipType[] Ships, ref int count)
{
    //statement
}
```

I mean should a char array have a `,` in between as you have done in `ref char[,] Board`?

If not, can you please mention the complete error that is shown?

Comment: [Multidimensional Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question

Comment: Hey @Rafalon  , Matthiee just answered my question .I was confused if  `ref char[,] Board` was valid or not.

Comment: My comment was more about indicating that the text you posted doesn't belong in the "answer" section (as you also said, it is a **question** and should therefore be posted either as a new *question* - with a bit of research first - or as a *comment* below OP's question)

Comment: @Rafalon thank you buddy got your point. Will try not to repeat it.